# JavaFX linechart xAxis values looks awful when data series are loaded into chart

Tags: javafx, axis, linechart

The problem:

When I load data series into a JavaFX LineChart, it is displayed like this:
[Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWaxD.png)

If I resize the window, data is instantly placed to the intended position, and X axis data is displayed just like it should. After that, everything displayed fine again no matter what I do.

After panel is resized:
[Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oIZo.png)

Can anyone tell me what can cause the problem? I don't feel the need to provide to code just yet, because I think this issue is independent from that. But let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's a bug (though I don't know if it's been reported). Setting the `animated` property to false is a workaround, I believe.

Comment: Yes it really helps. Thanks a lot. But this feels like a secondary solution.

Comment: Well, like I said, it's a bug (if I'm not mistaken). To properly solve the problem would require patching the JavaFX code itself.

Comment: Oh okay. Understood. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, if you're using a `CategoryAxis`, try specifying the categories on the axis as well (for instance, [during construction](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.collections.ObservableList))).

Comment: bug might be https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198830 - basically the category axis doesn't auto-size correctly (both workarounds by @Slaw are doing the job)